# Android ListView with lots of data - out of memory error

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, out-of-memory

I am publishing a bilingual dictionary application (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.akkzrt.szotarhude012013a), both language with more than 130 000 headwords. At program start I am preloading the data into two ArrayAdapters from two utf-8 text files stored in the assets folder, then I set the first adapter to my single ListView. At the top of that ListView I have a button to change to the other adapter (back and forth). I tested on some devices (samsung galaxy mini, asus tf201, samsung galaxy s 1 and 2, lg nexus 4, samsung galaxy nexus) and everything went fine.

Then one user came to me with his Sony Ericsson Experia MK16i. He was complaining that the application was not starting for him, just loading for a long time then running out of memory. At my google play developer admin page I have two java.lang.OutOfMemoryError crashes: one in dalvik.system.NativeStart.main and one in android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset.

What can I do about it? Shall I rewrite my whole loading module using sql databases and cursoradapter? I'd like to avoid that.

Every help and idea is highly appreciated. Thank you very much:
István

Comment: Have you thought about the possibilty to load your data when demanded? For example, when you are using Instagram app, when the scroll reach the bottom it automaticaly loads more photos. In your case you will load more data... Like a segmented load to not overflow your memory. It's just an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I loaded the whole database into the arrayadapter (memory) for better performance and for my other dictionaries (100000 entries) it didn't produce any out of memory errors even on weaker devices, I must have reached some kind of limit on those. (Although it's perfectly working on a samsung galaxy mini.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pagination for that data ,

> like 0-200 , 201-300 , etc .

use Custom adepter try some following logic .

```
int page= 100;
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
      if (postion>page)
{    
//     Adjust your array which filling your custom adepter 
//     Load next 100 items from database and notify your adepter 
}
//do else 
}
```

i assume that your data comes from database .

Comment: It's a good idea but the data isn't coming from sqlite database but a text file.

Comment: @mistvan how you read data from text file ? kind of local data parsing ?

Comment: I read it from assets /getAssets().open/ with a BufferedReader line by line (every line contains one headword).

Comment: i see , you should chunk the data if its too large to handle .

Comment: One more thing I don't understand: I am loading 1.5 and 2.4 MB text files into two List<String>. How come that they are occupying 24 MB of memory?